# What is the physics/chemistry behind gold dissolution in water/seawater?

Tags: solutions, solubility, metal

Global ocean contains some amount of dissolved gold (around 0.05-0.005 ppb).

1. Is it ions of gold?
2. Is it just suspended atomic gold (like water vapor in gases - just suspended molecules)?
3. Can pure gold (in metal state) be dissolved in pure water at any rate (even it is very slow process)?
4. If it can be dissolved in pure water what is the physics behind? just diffusion?